# Conversion of .ics attachment to native Outlook Calendar item without opening

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar

I am sending meeting invites from a PHP website but they end up as iCal attachments which is annoying. Since all the users are using Outlook, so I can think of sending the calendar invite as native outlook item. However, preferable way would be to let Outlook (any other client) convert iCal files on the fly withou getting the user involved. Kindly suggest a solution with working examples if possible. Thank you.

Comment: they will always have to be attachments that a user must  interact with - you cant force invites in to a users calander

Comment: Found solution. Header must contain 'inline' to specify outlook that ics needs to be inline and not end up as attachment.

Comment: What do you mean by "Header must contain 'inline'" ? Some extra meta tag has to be included with inline attribute in HTML <head> section ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending an attachment, send the message with the content type of "calendar/text" and the body of the message populated with contents of the ICS file.

Comment: outlook will  still prompt the recipient

Comment: To accept or decline the meeting request, but not to open an attachment and then save it.

Comment: I believe the op wanted no user interaction